# Admin login panel page keep refreshing

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

i have a problem when i want to login into my admin login panel i use username and password and the page refresh and stays the same without going to Settings.php path that i want to go in . if i can even try to add another script can give me permission to access that Settings.php file witout having to go trought that login.php file that causes the problem

*first code : Login.php file
*Second code : Settings.php file

```
<br/><br/><br/>
<div class="col-md-4"></div>
<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4><i class="fa fa-lock"></i>  login</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <?php echo form_open('/auth/login');?>
                <input type="text" placeholder="username" class="form-control " name="_name"  />
              <br/>
                <input type="password" placeholder="password" class="form-control " name="_pass"  />
                <br/>
                <input type="submit" name="login" class="btn btn-success" value="login" />
            <?php echo form_close();?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4"></div>
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<div class="col-md-3"></div>
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4><i class="fa fa fa-gear"></i> General Settings </h4>
        </div>
        <!--<form method="post" action="{site_url}/dashboard/save_settings" >-->
            <?php echo form_open('/dashboard/save_settings');?>
            <div class="panel-body">

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="site_name">Site Name</label>
                    <input name="site_name" class="form-control" id="site_name" value="{site_name}" type="text">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="site_mail">Email</label>
                    <input name="site_mail" class="form-control" id="site_mail" value="{site_mail}" type="text">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="site_desc">SEO description</label>
                    <textarea name="site_desc" class="form-control" id="site_desc" rows="3">{site_desc}</textarea>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="site_keys">SEO Keywords</label>
                    <textarea name="site_keys" class="form-control" id="site_keys" rows="3">{site_keys}</textarea>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="ad_code">Ad Code <small>(add ad code here like google adsense code or html code.)</small> </label>
                    <textarea name="ad_code" class="form-control" id="ad_code" rows="3">{ad}</textarea>
                </div>

                <!-- Social Media -->
                <h5><b>Social Media</b></h5>

                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon" id="facebook"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></span>
                    <input name="facebook" type="text" value="{facebook}" class="form-control" aria-describedby="facebook">
                </div>
                <br/>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon" id="twitter"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></span>
                    <input name="twitter" type="text" value="{twitter}" class="form-control" aria-describedby="twitter">
                </div>
                <br/>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon" id="googleplus"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></span>
                    <input name="googleplus" type="text" value="{googlep}" class="form-control" aria-describedby="googleplus">
                </div>

                <!-- END / Social Media -->
            </div>
            <div class="panel-footer">
                <!--<input  class="btn btn-success" type="submit" name="update" value="save" />-->
                <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" name="update"><i class="fa fa-save"></i> save</button>
            </div>
        <!--</form>-->
        <?php echo form_close();?>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3"></div>
```

Comment: I don't see any code here that would redirect the user to `settings.php`

Comment: You must to add php code if you would like someone help you, because with just HTML nobody can tell you where is the problem

Comment: @GabrieleCarbonai this is the authlogin php file "https://justpaste.it/1qm7f" i just want a solution that can create another admin login panel with my prefered username and pass and redirected to Setting.php file

Comment: @JonStirling this is the authlogin php file "justpaste.it/1qm7f" i just want a solution that can create another admin login panel with my prefered username and pass and redirected to Setting.php file

Comment: redirecting can come from the server, php or js. in php search for "header".